# How to pass kustomize configmap to helm values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I have kustomize deployment which installs helm chart.
This helm chart expects particular config map to exist and be mounted into pod.
configMapGenerator component generates config maps with hash suffix.

I.e. following kustomize section:

```
configMapGenerator:
  - name: my-config-map
    files:
      - my-file.json
```

Will generate config map with name `my-config-map-fdt4f87bkm`. I want to pass this config map to helm chart in `HelmRelease`:

```
    values:
        configmap: my-config-map
```

However this does not work, becasue real name of config map is `my-config-map-fdt4f87bkm`.
I want to keep using configMapGenerator to ensure that pods are rolled when there is conifguration change.

How I can pass real name of config map there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways. Either turn off suffix hash like:

```yaml
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config-map
  files:
  - my-file.json
  options:
    disableNameSuffixHash: true
```

or use kustomizeconfig.

(I'm considering by `HelmRelease` You mean FluxCD HelmRelease object and You provide values to it by `.spec.valuesFrom` not `.spec.values`)

for kustomize configuration, You have to provide a file with this content:

```
---
nameReference:
- kind: ConfigMap
  version: v1
  fieldSpecs:
  - path: spec/valuesFrom/name
    kind: HelmRelease
```

this file makes kustomize to append configMap suffixes to referenced configMaps for helm release values.
now set your `kustomization.yaml` to use this file:

```
---
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1

kind: Kustomization


resources:
- helmrelease.yaml

  
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config-map
  files:
  - my-file.json

    
configurations:
- kustomizeconfig.yaml
```

Output of `kustomize build` using kustomizeconfig file:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  my-file.json: |
    {
      "this": "that"
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config-map-mb2ck9tb4f
---
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: my-release
spec:
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: test
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: test
        namespace: test
      version: 1.1.1
  releaseName: my-release
  targetNamespace: kkk
  timeout: 15m
  valuesFrom:
  - kind: ConfigMap
    name: my-config-map-mb2ck9tb4f
```

Comment: Name refrence works well, thanks!